# openssl generating SHA-256

Tags: openssl

I'm trying to use openssl to  create a cryptographic hash of a file using HMAC-SHA-256. I'm confused as to why I'm seeing a 'no such file or directory' error on the output.

The key I'm using is in a file called mykey.txt.

This is my command:

```
openssl dgst -sha256 -hmac -hex hexkey:$(cat mykey.txt) -out hmac.txt /bin/ps
```

And the output

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

openssl dgst -sha256 -hmac -hex **-macopt** hexkey:$(cat mykey.txt) -out hmac.txt /bin/ps

Comment: At least on the OpenSSL (1.1.0f) on my system, that's exactly the same as if `-macopt hexkey...` was left out. That is, it calculates the HMAC using the key `-hex`, instead of using the parameter to `-macopt`.

Comment: Well, the question was "why am I seeing the error" - broken command arguments flow is often an irritating showstopper for further work. But sure, you're answer covers this much wider.

Comment: If all we care about is removing the immediate error message, then the command could have been reduced to just `openssl dgst -sha256 -hmac -hex -out hmac.txt /bin/ps` (or even further). That's probably not very useful, but at least it doesn't throw errors.

Comment: It's not about removing the error message by stepping back, but showing how to pass the `hexkey` argument itself.

Answer (score 11):

`-hmac` takes the key as an argument ([see manual](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man1/dgst.html)), so your command asks for an HMAC using the key `-hex`. `hexkey:...` is taken as a filename, since it doesn't start with a dash, and `openssl` doesn't take options after filenames, so the following `-out` is also a filename.

To get the HMAC with a key given as a hex string, you'll need to use `-mac hmac` and `-macopt hexkey:<key>`. Note that using `-hmac <key>` and 
`-mac hmac` together doesn't work, and `-macopt` requires `-mac hmac`.

Test:

```
openssl dgst -sha256 -hmac abc <<< "message"
openssl dgst -sha256 -hmac abc -macopt hexkey:12345678 <<< "message"
openssl dgst -sha256 -mac hmac -macopt hexkey:616263 <<< "message"
perl -MDigest::HMAC=hmac_hex -MDigest::SHA=sha256 \
    -le 'print(hmac_hex("message\n", "abc", \&sha256))'
```

All give the hash  `99592e56fcde028fb41882668b0cbfa0119116f9cf111d285f5cedb000cfc45a` which agrees with a random online HMAC calculator for message `message\n`, key `abc` or `616263` in hex. (Note the newline at the end of `message` here.)

So, it seems you'd probably want

```
openssl dgst -sha256 -mac hmac -macopt hexkey:$(cat mykey.txt) -out hmac.txt /bin/ps
```

---

Since we're talking about cryptography, which is hard; and OpenSSL, which doesn't always have the most easy-to-use interfaces, I would suggest also verifying everything yourself, at least twice, instead of taking my word for it.

Answer (score 0):

my 2 cents if You are on iOS (or Mac OS...)
tired of messing around I wrote it..

https://apps.apple.com/it/app/hmac-sha256generator/id6448465719?l=en