# openssl generating sha256

Tags: perl, openssl

i'm about to struggle with calculating a sha256 signature with the same result as <openssl dgst -sha256 -hmac> does calculate. this subject already was discussed in [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/444978/openssl-generating-sha-256). inspired by this content i wrote the small perl script in order to understand different implementations of sha256 hmac calculations.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Digest::SHA qw(sha256 hmac_sha256_hex hmac_sha256_base64);
use Digest::HMAC qw(hmac_hex);

my $msg = 'Value-corresponding_to_openssls_EVP_MD structure';
my $key = 'fq6if8aaxLTw0EHRAEkyvCbfa5O9BclbCCB6mtVsWO14KtyIdzIakzzlFGttMaw0';
my ($p1Sig, $p2Sig, $p3Sig, $odSig, $omSig);
my $DgstCmd = "echo \"$msg\" | openssl dgst -sha256 -hmac \"$key\"";

$p1Sig = hmac_sha256_hex($msg, $key);
$p2Sig = hmac_hex($msg, $key, \&sha256);
$p3Sig = hmac_sha256_base64($msg, $key);

$odSig = `$DgstCmd`;
$odSig =~ /= (\w*)/;

print "message\t<$msg>\nkey\t<$key>\nsignatures:\n  openssl  = <$1>\n  perlSHA  = <$p1Sig>\n  perlHMAC = <$p2Sig>\n  perlSHAbase = <$p3Sig>\n";

system ("openssl version");
```

the result is not as expected (run on win10):

```
message <Value-corresponding_to_openssls_EVP_MD structure>
key     <fq6if8aaxLTw0EHRAEkyvCbfa5O9BclbCCB6mtVsWO14KtyIdzIakzzlFGttMaw0>
signatures:
  openssl  = <a1a262e3d0393b076b53620d7924b04ae8c6d9c66a1a1aadd6c1b6e2fd27b8d8>
  perlSHA  = <2782c620c8c799d2c6b77d306cfca9be7dd2820effe66483d6b97dab7ada31f5>
  perlHMAC = <2782c620c8c799d2c6b77d306cfca9be7dd2820effe66483d6b97dab7ada31f5>
  perlSHAbase = <J4LGIMjHmdLGt30wbPypvn3Sgg7/5mSD1rl9q3raMfU>
OpenSSL 1.1.1g  21 Apr 2020
```

i so run it on a linux system (SMP PREEMPT Wed Nov 8 11:54:06 CET 2017 x86_64 GNU/Linux):

```
message <Value-corresponding_to_openssls_EVP_MD structure>
key     <fq6if8aaxLTw0EHRAEkyvCbfa5O9BclbCCB6mtVsWO14KtyIdzIakzzlFGttMaw0>
signatures:
  openssl  = <fadbde9a78101454d987d58ee00f6442f75a9f740202acbf9f1cb6933eeb27bf>
  perlSHA  = <2782c620c8c799d2c6b77d306cfca9be7dd2820effe66483d6b97dab7ada31f5>
  perlSHAbase = <J4LGIMjHmdLGt30wbPypvn3Sgg7/5mSD1rl9q3raMfU>
OpenSSL 1.1.0g  2 Nov 2017
```

all perl versions show the same result. openssl show different results. most interesting is the fact that different openssl versions show different results.

question 1: what is the reason for different results between openssl versions?
question 2: is there a solution in perl producing same result as `openssl dgst -sha256 -hmac`.

have fun

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> my $DgstCmd = "echo \"$msg\" | openssl dgst -sha256 -hmac \"$key\"";
> ```

`echo` adds a new-line to the message. Thus this does a digest of `"$msg\n"` on Linux, not a digest of `$msg`. I'm not sure what exactly it does on Windows though to get to this digest value, but it is definitely not just outputting `$msg`.

In other words: neither Perl nor openssl is wrong. You simply feed openssl a different input than you feed the Perl code.

Answer (score 0):

you are right, thank you steffen.

this problem arised with crpyto api. sometimes messages have to be signed with a hmac-sha256. my real probleam was the system time of my computer running ahaed of providers computer time.

if finished the testset perl and openssl with the c-version. for anyone interested in having the working testbed:

c-function, found in a previous chat, just packed as excecutable:

```
// using openssl; compile with [-Wall -g -O2] -lcrypto
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <openssl/hmac.h>

#define VERBOSE 1
void usage (char*);
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * mx_hmac_sha256 - wrapper to HMAC and EVP_sha256
 *-------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
unsigned char *mx_hmac_sha256 (const void *key, int keylen,
                              const unsigned char *data, int datalen,
                              unsigned char *result, unsigned int *resultlen) {
    return HMAC (EVP_sha256(), key, keylen, data, datalen, result, resultlen);
}

/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * main - begin coding
 *-------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
int main (int argc, char **argv) {
register char *p;
char flag = 0, *key = 0, *msg = 0, *buffer;
extern char *optarg;
extern int optind;
unsigned char *result = NULL;
unsigned int i, keylen, msglen, resultlen = (-1);
int c;

    while ((c = getopt(argc, argv, "?hvk:m:")) != -1) {
        switch (c) {
            case 'h':
            case '?':   usage (argv[0]);
                        return (0);
            case 'v':   flag |= VERBOSE;
                        break;
            case 'k':   key = optarg;
                        break;
            case 'm':   msg = optarg;
                        break;
            default:    printf ("unknown option <%c>\n", c);
                        usage (argv[0]);
                        return (-1);
        }
    }
    if ((argc - optind) > 0 ) {
        printf ("err: to many parameters, confused\n");
        usage (argv[0]);
        return (-2);
    }

    if (!key) {
        key = strdup ("security is awesome");
    }
    keylen = strlen(key);
    if (!msg) {
        msg = strdup ("this is highly sensitive user data");
    }
    msglen = strlen(msg);

    result = mx_hmac_sha256 ((const void *)key, keylen, (unsigned char *) msg, msglen, result, &resultlen);
    if (resultlen) {
        c = (2 * resultlen) + 1;
        buffer = malloc ((sizeof(char) *c));
        memset (buffer, 0, c);
        for (i = 0, p = buffer; i < resultlen; i++) {
          sprintf (p, "%02x", result[i]);
          p += 2;
        }
        if (flag & VERBOSE) {
            printf ("message: <%s>\nkey: <%s>\nsignature <%s>\n", key, msg, buffer);
        } else {
            printf ("%s",buffer);
        }
        return (0);
    } else {
        printf ("no signature\n");
    }
}

/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * usage
 *-------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
void usage (char *pgm) {
    printf ("usage: %s [-h?v] [-k key] [-m message]\n\
      h|? = this helptext\n\
      k   = key\n\
      m   = message\n\
      v   = verbose\n\n",pgm);
    return;
}
```

driving perl script:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Digest::SHA qw(sha256 hmac_sha256_hex hmac_sha256_base64);
use Digest::HMAC qw(hmac_hex);

my $msg = 'Value-corresponding_to_openssls_EVP_MD structure';
my $key = 'fq6if8aaxLTw0EHRAEkyvCbfa5O9BclbCCB6mtVsWO14KtyIdzIakzzlFGttMaw0';
my ($p1Sig, $p2Sig, $p3Sig, $odSig, $funcSig, $omSig);
#unix my $DgstCmd = "echo -n \"$msg\" | openssl dgst -sha256 -hmac \"$key\"";
my $DgstCmd = "echo|set /p=\"$msg\" | openssl dgst -sha256 -hmac \"$key\"";
#documented openssl-mac is not not existent anymore
#my $MacCmd = "echo -n \"$msg\" | openssl-mac -macopt digest:SHA256 \"$key\"";
my $FuncCmd = "HmacSha256Tst -k \"$key\" -m \"$msg\"";

$p1Sig = hmac_sha256_hex($msg, $key);
$p2Sig = hmac_hex($msg, $key, \&sha256);
$p3Sig = hmac_sha256_base64($msg, $key);

$odSig = `$DgstCmd`;
$odSig =~ /= (\w*)/;

$funcSig = `$FuncCmd`;
print "message\t<$msg>\nkey\t<$key>\nsignatures:\n  openssl  = <$1>\n  c-func   = <$funcSig>\n  perlSHA  = <$p1Sig>\n  perlHMAC = <$p2Sig>\n  perlSHAbase = <$p3Sig>\n";

system ("openssl version");
```

shows:

```
message <Value-corresponding_to_openssls_EVP_MD structure>
key     <fq6if8aaxLTw0EHRAEkyvCbfa5O9BclbCCB6mtVsWO14KtyIdzIakzzlFGttMaw0>
signatures:
  openssl  = <2782c620c8c799d2c6b77d306cfca9be7dd2820effe66483d6b97dab7ada31f5>
  c-func   = <2782c620c8c799d2c6b77d306cfca9be7dd2820effe66483d6b97dab7ada31f5>
  perlSHA  = <2782c620c8c799d2c6b77d306cfca9be7dd2820effe66483d6b97dab7ada31f5>
  perlHMAC = <2782c620c8c799d2c6b77d306cfca9be7dd2820effe66483d6b97dab7ada31f5>
  perlSHAbase = <J4LGIMjHmdLGt30wbPypvn3Sgg7/5mSD1rl9q3raMfU>
OpenSSL 1.1.1g  21 Apr 2020
```

have fun